# Unable to show footable-sort-indicator

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons, footable

I am using footable in my rails application.I implemented sorting and pagination for a page.Sorting and pagination working fine.But sortable glyphicon icon not showing on table headers.

I have included

In style sheets

```
footable.core.css
fonts
  footable.eot
  footable.svg
  footable.woff
  footable.ttf
```

In javascript directory

```
footable.all.min.js
```

But I didnt get those icons.Is there anything I am missing.Help me.

Comment: Can you create a simple fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Okay will try it and show

Comment: here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0fu1n2m6/1/#run&togetherjs=p7PvIguqMf).And i am unable to add some external files.

Answer (score 0):

Hei there, I had the same problem. I just used the predefined Glyphicons instead of the footable ones and it worked.

In the footable.core.css modify like this:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
 src: url('~/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('~/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
      url('~/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('~/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
      url('~/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg'); font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('~/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#footable') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
.footable.breakpoint > tbody > tr > td > span.footable-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #888888;
}
.footable > thead > tr > th > span.footable-sort-indicator {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

And voila! It should work. In the code above i just show the snippets that had been modified. For the glyphicons just search "bootstrap glyphicons hex" and will find the codes for any icon you wanna use.